# How [class] [attr] [style] directives work

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I examined ngStyle, ngClass directives [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts) but I still couldn't understand how these work:

```
<div [attr.role]="myAriaRole">
<div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful">
<div [style.width.px]="mySize">
```

Built-in directives don't select such an attribute: `class.extra-sparkle`. What kind of `selector` can select such html attribute? Which built-in directive handles this?

As far as I know html attributes with dot (`style.width.px`) are not legal already. Apparently the string withing square brackets don't passed directly as attributes. But where it is done? Which directive catches these notations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, these are not directives.

Angular compiler creates a view factory for each component with view nodes. For each view node the compiler defines a set of bindings types using the bitmask. There are different [binding types](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15090a8ad4a23dbe947ec48b581f1bf6a2da411e/packages/core/src/view/types.ts#L205) and hence different types of operations performed during change detection to reflect changes in the component class.

You probably know about the standard input mechanism that allows updating the property:

```
<div [prop]="myAriaRole">
```

The compiler creates the `TypeProperty` binding for it:

```
TypeProperty = 1 << 3
```

and hence the operation to update the element property is used during change detection.

The special syntax `attr.*`, `class.*` and `style.*` defines different type of bindings:

```
TypeElementAttribute = 1 << 0,
TypeElementClass = 1 << 1,
TypeElementStyle = 1 << 2,
```

so during change detection for each type of binding corresponding operation is used:

```
function CheckAndUpdateElement() {
    ...
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementAttribute -> setElementAttribute
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementClass     -> setElementClass
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementStyle     -> setElementStyle
    case BindingFlags.TypeProperty         -> setElementProperty;
```

To learn about Angular internals related to view and bindings I strongly recommend reading:

- [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)
- [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce)
- [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c)

Since all bindings are processed during change detection also read:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>The following code snippets are excerpted from the Angular.io docs.</sub>

What you're referring to is the [Binding target](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target).

```html
<img [src]="heroImageUrl">
```

The first div is referencing [Attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding).

```html
<table>
    <tr><td [attr.colspan]="1 + 1">One-Two</td></tr>
</table>
```

The second div is referencing [Class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding).

```html
<!-- toggle the "special" class on/off with a property -->
<div [class.special]="isSpecial">The class binding is special</div>

<!-- binding to `class.special` trumps the class attribute -->
<div class="special"
     [class.special]="!isSpecial">This one is not so special</div>
```

However, it is recommended to use `NgClass`.

The last div is referencing [Style binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding). Believe it or not, the third div is actually legal (or at least in Angular).

```html
<button [style.color]="isSpecial ? 'red': 'green'">Red</button>
<button [style.background-color]="canSave ? 'cyan': 'grey'" >Save</button>
```

However, it is recommended to use `NgStyle` instead.

So, in this case, it will bind the value of the variable to the element. (Except the `class` where it will evaluate whether the `isDelightful` variable is `true`.)

```html
<div [attr.role]="myAriaRole"></div>
<div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful"></div>
<div [style.width.px]="mySize"></div>
```

Here's a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tw3pzy) for you to play around with. :)

Comment: Thank you @Edrice, this wasn't the answer I was looking for but you led me to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @Edric specified [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target), the matter is the binding target. I firstly thought all of these are handled by a built-in directive

```
[attr.role]
[class.extra-sparkle]
[style.width.px]
```

like [ngClass](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.4/packages/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts#L10-L142) and [ngStyle](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.4/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts) but it is not. None of these are directives, they are just synonyms of this:

```
bind-attr.role
bind-class.extra-sparkle
bind-style.width.px
```

and the bind prefix are compiled at template parser [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b6431c60e66d0b4cdce17dff64872ddf86e70139/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L34). The "bind thing" is not a directive, [it is build-in feature that compiler already handles all the bound properties, attributes etc](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0833b59aabddd541820379f3cbc69c62a5787bcc/packages/core/src/view/element.ts#L75).