# understanding how @HostBinding works in angular for toggleClass directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I came across the following angular directive:

```
import { Directive , HostListener , HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appDropdown]'
})

export class DropdownDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

    @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }
}
```

While surfing code online , basically the code only toggles the `open` class on the element the directive is used on , so this directive can be used like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what i don't understand is the below line of code in the directive:

```
 @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
```

Whats exactly is it doing and how exactly does it function ? I am not quite understanding the above line of code. can somebody please explain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@HostBinding` allows you to define a binding for a host element of your directive. As you probably know there's a [special binding syntax for the class](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) that looks like this:

```
<element [class.class-name]="expression">...</element>
```

You can read specifics of implementation in [How [class] [attr] [style] directives work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639851/2545680).

In your example the `li` element is the host element and the expression is `isOpen` so the host binding your referenced essentially defines the following:

```
<li class="dropdown" appDropdown [class.open]="isOpen">
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [link](https://alligator.io/angular/hostbinding-hostlistener/). To sum it up:

@HostBinding decorator lets you update properties on the host element of the directive. What that means, as far as i understand, is that Angular change detection will evaluate the variables (expresions) decorated by it and propagate changes to the attributes you 'bind' in the host element (add\remove class in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to not mix **@HostBinding** with **Renderer2** in a directive to change DOM style. Not sure why, but gets unexpected results.

Example Below:

```
//: WORKS: ENTER_A + EXIT_A
//: WORKS: ENTER_B + EXIT_B

//: FAILS: ENTER_A + EXIT_B
//: FAILS: ENTER_B + EXIT_A

import {
  Directive    ,

  HostBinding  ,
  HostListener ,

  Renderer2    ,
  ElementRef   } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBetterHighlight]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective {

  constructor(private ER: ElementRef, private REN:Renderer2 ) {}

  changeBgColor( color_string: string ){
    this.REN.setStyle( this.ER.nativeElement, 'background-color', color_string);
  }

  //Use CamelCase because DOM does not understand "background-color"
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor: string = "blue";

  @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover(ED: Event){
    //this.changeBgColor( "magenta");  //<<<<<< [ ENTER_A ]
    this.backgroundColor = 'magenta';  //<<<<<< [ ENTER_B ]
    console.log("[MOUSE_ENTER]");
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(ED: Event){
    //this.changeBgColor("green"); //<<<<<<<<<< [ EXIT_A ]
    this.backgroundColor = 'green'; //<<<<< [ EXIT_B ]
    console.log("[MOUSE_LEAVE]");
  }

}
```